# Django add an attribute class form in __init__.py

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

My form class

```
from django import forms

class Form(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name ', max_length=100)
```

My app file `__init__.py`

```
from django import forms
from my_app.forms import Form
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

def register(form):
 form.captcha=CaptchaField()

register(Form)
```

Code in `__init__.py` add an attribute captcha but it is not on the page.

I tried so

My form class

```
from django import forms

class Form(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name ', max_length=100)
    captcha=CaptchaField()
```

It works, but I have a different! I want to add a сaptcha many forms.
I want to add the captcha without changing the form classes. I want to change the form classes during initialization.
How to do it???

Comment: Would a superclass (subclass of `django.forms.Form`) with the `captcha` attribute solve your problem?

Comment: Please read more.
I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the field to `form.fields`, not just `form`.

However this is not really the way to do this. Instead, you should make all your forms inherit from a shared parent class, which defines the `captcha` field.

Comment: It works
MyForm.base_fields['foo'] = CharField(max_length=100)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from a comment, have a base class inherit from `django.forms.Form`, and subclass it for all the forms you want a `captcha` field on;

```
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
from django.forms import Form

class CaptchaMixin():
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

class ActualForm(CaptchaMixin, Form):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to add a class forms attribute in  __init__py?